# Nginx+Railsコンテナでdocker-composeしてブラウザでアクセスすると500の内部サーバエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, docker-compose

**実現したいこと**
docker-composeで立ち上げたRailsアプリに、ブラウザからアクセスする。

**解決したい事象**
下記のコンテナ構成でdocker-compose upでコンテナを立ち上げました。

- APサーバ：Rails
- Webサーバ：Nginx
- DBサーバ：MySQL

そして、docker-compose upではエラーが出なかったので、ブラウザでアプリへアクセスしたところ、
下記エラー画面（500 Internal Server Error）が表示され、アプリの画面が正常に表示できません。
何が原因として考えられるか、また解決方法についてお伺いしたい次第です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なお、先日までは、「Rails」+「MySQL」という構成でDockerを使用しており（Nginxなし）、
その際は問題なくアプリの画面が表示できていました。
この度、Nginxを使用したいと思い、Nginxのコンテナも追加しました。

**試したこと**
サーバ側のエラーメッセージに
「worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream」
とあったので、その内容を調査し、下記のQiita記事の内容から、
worker_connectionsを増加させる記述をNginx設定ファイル（nginx.conf）へ行いました。
しかし、事象・エラーメッセージ共に変化せずでした。
[[Nginx]worker_connectionsとworker_rlimit_nofileの値は何がいいのか？](https://qiita.com/mikene_koko/items/85fbe6a342f89bf53e89)

現在、nginx.confの内容に原因があるのではと推測し、
エラーメッセージで検索し、調査を続けているところですが、
並行してご質問させていただきました。

**サーバ側エラーメッセージ**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**nginx.conf**

```
# プロキシ先の指定
# Nginxが受け取ったリクエストをバックエンドのpumaに送信
upstream myapp {
  # ソケット通信したいのでpuma.sockを指定
  server unix:///myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  # ドメインもしくはIPを指定
  server_name 192.168.99.100;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  # ドキュメントルートの指定
  root /app/public;

  client_max_body_size 100m;
  error_page 404             /404.html;
  error_page 505 502 503 504 /500.html;
  try_files  $uri/index.html $uri @myapp;
  keepalive_timeout 5;

  # リバースプロキシ関連の設定
  location @myapp {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://myapp;
  }
}

# エラーを受けて追加したが動作変わらず（2020/6/17）
worker_rlimit_nofile 83000;

events {
  worker_connections 4096; # 1つのworkerプロセスが開ける最大コネクション数
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
      （他情報は略）
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  test-db:
      （他情報は略）
    ports:
      - '3307:3306' # ローカルPCから接続するために設定
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails/Dockerfile
    command: bundle exec pumactl start
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - public-data:/myapp/public
      - tmp-data:/myapp/tmp
      - log-data:/myapp/log
      - sockets:/myapp/tmp/sockets
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - db
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - public-data:/myapp/public
      - tmp-data:/myapp/tmp
      - sockets:/myapp/tmp/sockets
    depends_on: 
      - app
volumes:
  db-volume:
  public-data:
  tmp-data:
  log-data:
  sockets:
```

**Puma.rbの内容**

```rb
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart

app_root = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
bind "unix://#{app_root}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"

stdout_redirect "#{app_root}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_root}/log/puma.stderr.log", true
```

**NginxのDockerfile**

```
FROM nginx

# インクルード用のディレクトリ内を削除
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

# Nginxの設定ファイルをコンテナにコピー
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf

# ビルド完了後にNginxを起動
CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;' -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

#### railsのDockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5
# apt-utils関連のエラーを表示させないようにする
ENV DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS yes
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \ 
                       libpq-dev \      
                       nodejs \
                       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 作業ディレクトリの作成、設定
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# ホスト側（ローカル）のGemfileを追加する
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

# Gemfileのbundle install
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
RUN mkdir -p tmp/sockets

# Expose volumes to frontend
VOLUME /app/public
VOLUME /app/tmp
```

**ディレクトリ構成**

```
app/
bin/
config/
  -puma.rb
   （ほかは省略）
core
db/
docker/
　-nginx/
    -Dockerfile
    -nginx.conf
  -rails/
    -Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
lib/
log/
nginx/
package.json
public/
Rakefile
README.md
spec/
storage/
tmp/
　-sockets/
  -pids/
  （他は省略）
vendor/
```

なお、teratailでも同様の質問を行っておりますが、
teratailで何か情報の更新がありましたら、すぐにこちらに情報反映させていただきます。
何卒ご了承いただきますよう、お願い申し上げます。
[teratailの質問リンク](https://teratail.com/questions/270839)

不足情報等ございましたら、お手数をお掛けし恐縮ではございますが、
ご指摘いただけますと幸いです。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。
「①nginx.confのディレクティブを考慮できていないこと」と「②ビルドしたdockerイメージに設定が反映されていないこと」が原因でした。
＜詳細＞
①worker_rlimit_nofile は設定ファイルのトップレベルに記載すべき項目(参考→ context: main)ですが，私は /etc/nginx/nginx.conf の httpディレクティブにincludeしてしまっていたため、
worker_rlimit_nofileを削除しました。
②nginx.confはビルドと関係なくdocker-compose upの時のみ読み込まれると思っていましたが、ビルド時にも読み込まれるため、docker-compose buildからやり直したところ、正常にブラウザでアクセスすることができました。